# applying display tag to my project but failed in struts config file

Tags: struts-1, displaytag

I am applying display tag to my jsp in struts but not able to do it please check out

1.strutsconfig

```
<form-beans><form-bean name="DailysheetForm" type="com.myapp.struts.DailysheetForm"/>
</formbean>
<action input="/" path="/DailysheetList" name="DailysheetForm"  scope="request"            type="com.myapp.struts.DialysheetListAction">
   <forward name="success" path="/DailysheetList.jsp"/>
</action>
```

2.Form

```
public class DailysheetForm extends ActionForm 
 {
// some getter and setter methods i used like receiptno
   protected ArrayList arraylist;
   public ArrayList getArraylist()
     {
       return arraylist;
     }

public void setArraylist(ArrayList arraylist) {

    this.arraylist = arraylist;

}
```

3.Action Class

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    ArrayList dailysheetdata;
    DailysheetForm dailyform = (DailysheetForm) form;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Stonecrusher?"
                        + "user=Stonecrusher&password=xxxxxx");
    System.out.println("Connection"+connect);
    dailysheetdata = StoneCrusherData.getDailysheetData(connect);

    dailyform.setArraylist(dailysheetdata) ;
    return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
     }
```

JSP

```
<display:table id="data"  name="requestScope.DailysheetForm.arraylist"requestURI="/DailysheetList" pagesize="10" >
  <display:column property="receiptno" title="RECEIPTNO" sortable="true"/>
  <display:column property="cutomername" title="CUSTOMER NAME" sortable="true"/>
</display:table>
<display:table id="data" name="requestScope.DailysheetForm.arraylist" requestURI="/DailysheetList" pagesize="10" >
  <display:column property="receiptno" title="RECEIPTNO" sortable="true"/>
  <display:column property="cutomername" title="CUSTOMER NAME" sortable="true"/>
</display:table>
```

It is not working and basically I am getting data to dailysheetdate which is arraylist in my Action Class and I want to display it in jsp with pagination. I know I was wrong please help me how to do it.

Comment: Your strutsconfig isn't valid XML.  There's a `</formbean>` closing tag that shouldn't be there.

Comment: And check whether you placed `<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>` in your jsp or not

and you should add `displaytag-export-poi-1.2` 
`displaytag-portlet-1.2` jar files to lib directory

Comment: @Clarence i added taglib and all required jar files sorry for not stating it and my home page has link to `<html:link forward="Dailysheetdata">data retrieval</html:link>` and my struts config file has `<forward name="Dailysheetdata" path="/DailysheetList.do"/>`  when i click it url displayed is [link]http://localhost:8080/Dailysheet/DailysheetList.do but does not do any action .and i want is when my required data is in arraylist dailysheetdata in Action Class and i want to display them in jsp with pagination

Comment: i edited my answer check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your jar files whether you placed all required jars in to lib or not..
still have a problem paste your Error here..

[See the Tutorial for Display Tag](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-display-tag-table-decorator-example-1.html)

then you need not Specify `input` and `name` attributes in `<action>` in `strutsconfig.xml`

i.e  your code should like ethis

```
<action path="/DailysheetList" scope="request"  type="com.myapp.struts.DialysheetListAction">
   <forward name="success" path="/DailysheetList.jsp"/>
</action>
```

then definitely Action Class will execute..

And one more thing by seeing your action class code i does't know whether `StoneCrusherData` object is created or not.. check below line also

```
dailysheetdata = StoneCrusherData.getDailysheetData(connect);
```

Comment: i implemented them from same tutorial but mine is not working and i stated error in above comment it is not going into action class when clicked link dataretrieval which is defined above may be wrong in my strutsconfig .xml

Comment: i used removed the form and used attribute and solved ,i edited the struts config file as above